# How to keep mic open in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I´m using DialogFlow to create a chatbot. I want to keep the mic open along a conversation so the user doesn´t have to press the mic button every time.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [conv.ask](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment#create_functions_to_handle_requests) to automatically trigger the opening of mic and accept user input, handle it & respond accordingly.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you're currently using to reply? What do you mean by "press the mic button"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to Dialogflow test console ("Try it now" prompt) - it doesn't seems you can.

But I will assume that you are referring to Google Assistant integration.

First of all you will have to end each answer with additional question, eg "Can I help you with anything else?" - this will be verified when you will deploy your bot to production in Actions on Google console. For each intent that you want to keep the microphone listening, you will have to make sure that it has "Set this intent as end of conversation" option disabled.

Comment: Thank for the answer.